# Do we have only one Store for an Ember App

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, store

I am confused how Store works in Ember. Do we have one store managing all the models in an ember app? Is it possible to make multiple stores for multiple models? I have right now three models and as it seems they are using the same store. Would it be possible to have different stores for different models?

Comment: what's the use-case for having different store for different models?